# Installing IBM JRE on Windows (a non-IBM machine)

Tags: java, windows, ibm-jre

I'm developing a Java 5.0 application that connects to Websphere Application Server default messaging queues.

My application will be deployed on Windows server (with sun JDK installed by default), in order to connect to the Websphere queues I have two choices:

1. Using IBM JRE
2. Using sun JRE, copying some IBM JRE's jars, setting some JVM properties, ...

The idea is, the second choice was painful, I'm trying to go with the first choice.

My question is: can I install an IBM JRE 5.0 on a non-IBM windows machine?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two "answers".

- **Technically**, yes, it's possible and it works no problem.
- **Legally**, I don't know if the IBM JRE is licensed for use or distribution by itself. It was my impression that it was licensed only as part of another IBM product (like WebSphere MQ, or one of the Rational tools), which would mean you would have to license the other product on the machine before installing the JRE, and you would use the installer for the other produce to get the JRE onto the machine.

Best to clear this latter question up with an IBM representative.

Answer (score 4):

The reason the IBM JVM is so hard to get hold of is most likely that they want you to pay some money for it.

The "Easiest Way" to get a IBM JDK for Windows is probably from here: (but that is without support) https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/jdk/eclipse/

---

Edit:  Do the product you want to connect to not include a set of client jar files you just need to add to your application?

Comment: I believe the license agreement for JREs based on Sun's are that they are only redistributable as part of a larger product whose main purpose is not to be a JRE. This appears to be what caused Linux distros to object to including it. Of course there is OpenJDK now.

Comment: I do not think the IBM J9 JVM is based on the Sun Hotspot - they may have licensed the libraries though.

Comment: The reason for the Linux distribution problem was primarily that the license did not allow for redistribution with a Linux distribution at all.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there is a free-to-download-and-distribute IBM JRE. There are certainly IBM Win32 JREs that are not tied to IBM PCs and if you own certain IBM products, you can redistribute the JRE as per their terms.

For example, this excerpt comes from the pithily titled *IBM Rational Application Developer for WebSphere Software 7.5.2 GA* [license](http://www-03.ibm.com/software/sla/sladb.nsf/lilookup/7008F5CA29865FBD002575860035C724?opendocument&li_select=8D0BF15470ACC913002575860035C703):

> DISTRIBUTION OF JRE REDISTRIBUTABLES
>
> You may distribute the software listed
>   below (the "JRE Redistributables")
>   only in conjunction with Your
>   application and subject to the
>   following terms: (1) Your
>   redistribution of the JRE
>   Redistributables must be in object
>   code and must comply with all
>   technical and user directions provided
>   with the Program; (2) Your application
>   must redistribute other
>   Redistributables identified in this
>   license with the JRE Redistributables
>   unless Your application is designed to
>   run only on general computer devices
>   (e.g., desktops and servers) and not
>   pervasive devices; (3) You may not
>   remove any copyright or notice files
>   contained in the JRE Redistributables;
>   (4)You will indemnify IBM or third
>   parties that provide IBM products
>   ("Third Parties") from and against any
>   third party claim arising out of the
>   use or distribution of Your
>   application; (5) You may not use the
>   same path name as the original
>   files/modules; (6) You may not use
>   IBM's or Third Parties' names or
>   trademarks in connection with the
>   marketing of Your applications without
>   IBM's or Third Parties' prior written
>   consent; and (7) IBM or Third Parties
>   provide copies of these files or
>   modules "AS IS," i.e., You are
>   responsible for all technical
>   assistance for Your application.
>
> In Your license agreement with the
>   recipient, You will notify the
>   recipient that these files or modules
>   may not be 1) used for any purpose
>   other than to enable Your application,
>   2) copied (except for backup
>   purposes), 3) further distributed
>   without Your application or 4) reverse
>   assembled, reverse compiled, or
>   otherwise translated.
>
> The JRE Redistributables software can
>   be found in the following directory on
>   the installation media:
>
> `/jdk/jre`

You can lookup/search IBM software licenses at http://www.ibm.com/software/sla/sladb.nsf.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can download an IBM 1.5 JRE on a non-IBM windows machine.  Go [here](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24023276) to download the IBM 1.5 SR9 JRE as a .pak file.  Simply rename it as a zip and unpack it.

Answer (score 0):

no .. you cannot, this JRK/JDK is part of WebSphere Application Server, legally you cannot use it unless you purchased the license of WAS and the application is used to connect to the WAS